# iOS 12 specific problem: Core Data External Storage Binary Data corruption

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios12

I've spent the better part of a workday trying to solve this.

**Background**

I have a simple core data model, with books and reading sessions. The books have covers (images) that are stored as binary data with "Allows External Storage".

On iOS 11.4 and below, everything works fine all the time. When I save a new session everything gets updated properly.

**Problem**

Since iOS 12, when I create a new reading session and link it to the book, about every *second* time, core data generates a SQL statement that also updates the book cover field, sometimes resulting in a bad reference (to file on disk) which often results in the cover being *nil* when restarting the app, and almost always creates duplicate copy of the cover on disk (as can be seen in Simulator's `_EXTERNAL_DATA` folder).

In-memory context and objects remain correct though (and everything in the UI is therefore OK), until the app is restarted, then the cover is often *nil*.

**iOS 12 specific**

On iOS 12, I can deterministically reproduce the error in the simulator, on physical devices, and users have reported the error as well. I cannot reproduce the error on iOS 11.4, and no users reported the error previous to iOS 12.

**Steps taken**

- I've enabled "`-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`", so it shouldn't be that I'm accessing anything from the wrong queue. I've also enabled "`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3`" so that I can see exactly what gets written.
- I've made sure the Book instance (and therefore the cover) is not modified by my code before the association with the new Session by checking `hasChanges`, just before I do `newSession.book = book` and `context.save()`.
- To be 100% sure I'm not touching the cover property on any thread I've short-circuited my getters and setters for that property. No improvement.
- I've tried using `objectID` to request an instance of the book just before the association and save. No improvement.
- I've even tried the option where the context keeps strong references to all objects, just to make sure it was not some kind of memory management issue. No improvement.

**Question**

Any ideas for next steps?

**Status update**

This is a defect in iOS 12. See accepted answer below for a detailed description of a resonable workaround.

Comment: I think I am having the exact same issue. Any workarounds or solutions for this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I think we hit the same bug, although with a bit other use case. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109189

Comment: We experience that saving images to coredata external storage succeeds, but after we restart the app, the images are not accesible anymore and return nil. Major iOS 12 bug. :(

Comment: May also be related: http://ileyf.cn.openradar.appspot.com/44884416

Comment: Report it on the Bugtracker, the more the better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update:** The underlying Core Data issue appears to be resolved in iOS 12.1 (verified in *beta 4*).  We will keep the workaround described below in our app, and won't be recommending using the *External Storage* option any time soon.

---

After talking to Apple engineers and filing the [Radar mentioned above](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4990685501456384), we couldn’t wait around for a fix, so we took the hit and switched to storing files on the filesystem and managing it directly ourselves.

Another alternative that we considered was migrating our model not to allow External Storage for BLOBs, but I don't know what impact that would have had on performance and I was also worried about a model migration at a time when this part of iOS seems to be unstable, especially after reading stories like this in the past: [Core Data: don’t store large files as binary data – Alexander Edge – Medium](https://medium.com/@alexedge/binary-attributes-and-migration-in-core-data-bc7cfb3029fc)

It wasn't too much of a pain to implement local storage ourselves.  You just need to have a unique identifier for each record that you can use to create a filename so you can map files to records.  We added an extension to our Managed Object subclass with methods for reading, writing and deleting the files.  Now, instead of calling e.g. `article.photo = image.pngData()`, we now need to call something like `article.savePhoto(image.pngData())` and then we do similar when we want to retrieve the image.  You can also add some code to these methods to support backwards compatibility with any images that are currently stored in Core Data.

Deletion was a little more tricky because our objects are deleted from multiple places in the code, including cascading deletes.  In the end I opted to do it in the managed object's `prepareForDeletion` method but it is not ideal.  There is plenty of discussion of how best to implement this here: [cocoa - How to handle cleanup of external data when deleting *unsaved* Core Data objects? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603227/how-to-handle-cleanup-of-external-data-when-deleting-unsaved-core-data-objects)

Finally, to prevent our app crashing when a non-Optional binary attribute has disappeared because of this bug, I override `awakeFromFetch` in my Managed Object subclass to ensure that any required attributes are not nil, and if they are, I set them to a placeholder image so that they can be saved without the validation failing.

Comment: Nice! I ended up solving this issue almost exactly the same way. I also could not wait until Apple fixes this. Also I feel that files whose URLs I know and can access directly is a better solution for me in the long run.

Comment: Funny, we did the same thing. We now store images on filesystem with a unique UUID stored in coredata.

Comment: This Core Data issue now appears to be fixed in iOS 12.1 beta 4.

Comment: @rodhan we also experienced this problem and used a workaround, but we also have couple of crashes that seem related but a bit different. is this familiar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53300900/core-data-binary-data-with-allows-external-storage-crashes

Comment: @Zsolt that definitely looks like the same bug is causing the data corruption that causes the crash.  I answered your question with some details of how you could check on the filesystem directly to see if the file actually exists or not. That might help you.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue STILL is not fixed in iOS 12.1.1

Comment: AND? Everybody says that it is bad but nobody have been suggested a concrete solution for years

Comment: I'm getting the same crash / error in iOS 16