# safari app extension crashes after a few seconds for hello world project

Tags: swift, xcode, safari, safari-app-extension

1. open xcode
2. file > new >project > Cocoa app
3. file > new > target > safari extension
4. compile and run extension
5. select safari.
6. xcode compiles with no errors.

Safari opens for a few seconds then crashes.

this is the output of the debug window.

> 2018-10-10 15:27:18.039905-0700 Safari[1020:16719] [SQLiteStore]
>   Failed to acquire database store coordination lock at
>   /Users//Library/Safari/Favicon Cache/favicons.db-lock:
>   [35: Resource temporarily unavailable] 2018-10-10 15:27:18.040155-0700
>   Safari[1020:16719] [SQLiteStore] Failed to acquire exclusive access to
>   database at
>   file:///Users//Library/Safari/Favicon%20Cache/favicons.db.
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.041141-0700 Safari[1020:16719] [SQLiteStore]
>   Failed to acquire database store coordination lock at
>   /Users//Library/Safari/Favicon Cache/favicons.db-lock:
>   [35: Resource temporarily unavailable] 2018-10-10 15:27:18.041226-0700
>   Safari[1020:16719] [SQLiteStore] Failed to acquire exclusive access to
>   database at
>   file:///Users//Library/Safari/Favicon%20Cache/favicons.db.
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.041331-0700 Safari[1020:16719] [SQLiteStore]
>   Falling back to an in-memory store 2018-10-10 15:27:18.042877-0700
>   Safari[1020:16719] [FaviconPersistence] Using in-memory representation
>   for database /Users//Library/Safari/Favicon
>   Cache/favicons.db 2018-10-10 15:27:18.125466-0700 Safari[1020:16771]
>   [SQLiteStore] Failed to acquire database store coordination lock at
>   /Users//Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/TabSnapshots/Metadata.db-lock:
>   [35: Resource temporarily unavailable] 2018-10-10 15:27:18.125660-0700
>   Safari[1020:16771] [SQLiteStore] Failed to acquire exclusive access to
>   database at
>   file:///Users//Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/TabSnapshots/Metadata.db.
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.235987-0700 Safari[1020:16718] flock failed to
>   lock maps file: errno = 35 2018-10-10 15:27:18.236343-0700
>   Safari[1020:16718] flock failed to lock maps file: errno = 35
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.293614-0700 Safari[1020:16718] Failed to acquire
>   exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   AutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10
>   15:27:18.299481-0700 Safari[1020:16718] Failed to acquire exclusive
>   access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire exclusive access to
>   AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db.
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.300530-0700 Safari[1020:16718] Failed to acquire
>   exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   AutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10
>   15:27:18.304153-0700 Safari[1020:16718] Failed to acquire exclusive
>   access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire exclusive access to
>   AutoFill corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db.
>   2018-10-10 15:27:18.620185-0700 Safari[1020:16763] Failed to acquire
>   exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   AutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10
>   15:27:18.623032-0700 Safari[1020:16773] [CrowdsourcedAutoFill] Unable
>   to read cloud AutoFill correction sets, error: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened
>   because it doesn’t exist." 2018-10-10 15:27:18.629453-0700
>   Safari[1020:16763] Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to
>   acquire exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10 15:27:18.675086-0700
>   Safari[1020:16765] [CloudBookmarks] Error fetching remote migration
>   state: Error
>   Domain=com.apple.SafariBookmarksSync.CloudBookmarksErrorDomain Code=0
>   "(null)" 2018-10-10 15:27:18.771588-0700 Safari[1020:16718]
>   [RemotePlistController] The downloaded plist could not be loaded:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened
>   because it doesn’t exist." 2018-10-10 15:27:19.161007-0700
>   Safari[1020:16773] Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to acquire
>   exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   AutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10 15:27:19.167933-0700
>   Safari[1020:16773] Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to
>   acquire exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10 15:27:19.279743-0700
>   Safari[1020:16763] [RemotePlistController] The downloaded plist could
>   not be loaded: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file
>   couldn’t be opened because it doesn’t exist." 2018-10-10
>   15:27:20.064438-0700 Safari[1020:16763] Failed to acquire exclusive
>   access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at AutoFillCorrections.db.
>   Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite
>   store at AutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10 15:27:20.081337-0700
>   Safari[1020:16763] Failed to acquire exclusive access to AutoFill
>   corrections SQLite store at CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. Failed to
>   acquire exclusive access to AutoFill corrections SQLite store at
>   CloudAutoFillCorrections.db. 2018-10-10 15:27:20.084003-0700
>   Safari[1020:16763] [CrowdsourcedAutoFill] Neither local nor cloud
>   classification correction databases could be opened Program ended with
>   exit code: 0

I've tried restarting my computer.

I've tried cleaning the project.

I've tried deleting meta data with

```
xatter -cr .
```

I've tried all three at once.

Comment: Is this any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586564/ios-12-specific-problem-core-data-external-storage-binary-data-corruption

Answer (score 3):

Xcode debugger has a tendency to kill the extension process if it doesn't receive any events from the content script. From my observations, this is completely okay, and in production your app will not die as easily *(edited: this isn't true, look at the bottom of the post)*.

To circumvent this behavior you might want to add this snippet to your `script.js`:

```js
setInterval(() => safari.extension.dispatchMessage("ping", {}), 1000);
```

It will make content script send a message named "ping" to the extension every second. This should be enough to keep your extension alive. Again, this is only really needed for debugging, your production build won't need this line to work reliably *(edited: this isn't true, look at the bottom of the post)*.

Keep in mind that by default content scripts are only injected on *.webkit.org pages. This is determined by the value of `SFSafariToolbarItem` property in your extension's `Info.plist` file. For testing purposes, you might want to enable your extension on all websites like so:

```xml
<key>SFSafariWebsiteAccess</key>
<dict>
  <key>Level</key>
  <string>All</string>
</dict>
```

Be careful, content script is not injected into an empty tab, so be sure to load some remote page.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, Safari actually kills extensions  in production builds the same way as it does in the debugger. So setInterval() hack is still relevant in that case. This only applies to extensions without a popover.

Comment: I have created extension build and install it in safari but it still process after 30 of inactivity

Comment: After several months I discovered there are other circumstances under which this behavior won't occur. E.g. for me Xcode never kills extensions with a popover view controller.

Comment: This answer is WRONG. You should not use `setTimeout` but `setInterval`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @ChristopherJ. I edited my answer to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

At the first run you should select your Cocoa App target and only after this run the extension. Please, try build and run your app at first and say if it helped.

Comment: This worked for me kinda.  The extension shows up and it works.  But I get the same errors in the console.